# Elasticsearch OutOfMemoryError Java heap space

Tags: java, elasticsearch, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am running an 8 cores, 32g RAM elasticsearch node with 5 shards, 400 million (small) documents.

Everything works great until I run an agg search, then shards start failing with:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have [changed heap size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) with:
`export ES_HEAP_SIZE=16g` (also `ES_MAX_MEM` and `ES_MIN_MEM` to same)

also changed the `yml` file for elasticsearch:

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

and even (recommended by install documents):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Restart service and still no no impact, still `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Any other suggestions? other than don't run agg queries?

query is:

```
https://localhost:9200/my_index_name/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_hostname": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "hostname"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What version are you running? What aggregation query are you running? Is it possible to limit amount of documents to put in the aggregate result with a filter?

Comment: Version: 1.1.1, Build: f1585f0, JVM: 1.7.0_72

Comment: The aggregation query is on a field that exists in each document.  The query is an attempt to count the unique instances of the contents of this field.  Limiting what it is run on would skew the results.  I don't anticipate running this query often and wouldn't mind if it ran slow.  But when a shard fails, I get inconsistent results.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#fielddata-size

Comment: Take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html

Answer (score 27):

I think I have discovered the error.  I was using 'service' to run elasticsearch and therefore my environment variables got stripped.  I had to update the `/etc/default/elasticsearch` file with the correcct env variables (specifically the `ES_HEAP_SIZE=16g`).

So far it's running well and app is not erroring.

Answer (score 18):

The correct way to update Java heap size for Elasticsearch 5 is not `EXPORT _JAVA_OPTIONS` or `EXPORT ES_HEAP_SIZE` or using command line parameters.  As far as I can tell, all of these are overridden by a configuration file in your Elasticsearch install directory, `config/jvm.options`.  To change these settings you need to edit these lines in that file:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

Comment: Just a note for Windows users: `jvm.options` is used to determine Java options when [installing elasticsearch service](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/windows.html#windows-service), but after that any change in `jvm.options` will have no effect until you recreate the service.

Comment: On Elasticsearch 2.3.3 I had to set both `ES_HEAP_SIZE` and `ES_JAVA_OPTS` to get any value but the default. This meant I didn't have to use `config/jvm.options`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, here is how you fix this in newer versions of ELK (Elasticsearch, Kibana, Logstash) (v 5.0+):

Configure your `jvm.options` file to allocate more memory on the heap.
The options you will need to configure are the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options, which by default are set to 1 Gigabyte of RAM (`-Xms1G` and `-Xmx1G`). The recommended size for this is no more than half of your system RAM. For example, on a PC with 32GB RAM, you would set set the following: `-Xms16G` and `-Xmx16G`.

This file can be found at `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` on most ELK installs.

The docs have much more detailed info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-heap-size